# How to write to a file by reading another file and making some changes in it

Tags: java

Hi, I am trying to read a text file and then writing the read data to a new file in Java by changing some fields in data read from the first file. I am stuck here: I can read file but the selective modification is very difficult, I can not understand how to modify particular part of the line in a file? The text file is details.txt, and its contents are like:

peter,New York,2331.32

walsh,California,3224.43

and so on. Now, I want to modify the double values with an array containing the updated values like following:

```
Double[] updatedValues = {33231.23,32344.34};
```

Can anybody please tell me how to update the double values by reading the values from array and writing those values to a new text file?

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to split line using `String.split()` method, compose new line and then write it to the file. For example:

```
String[] data = line.split(",");
data[2] = "" + updatedValues[i];
// now join array of data back and write it to the new file.
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    double[] updatedValues = {33231.23,32344.34 .....
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("file1"));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("file2"));
    for (int i = 0; sc.hasNextLine(); i++) {
        String l = sc.nextLine();
        l = l.substring(0, l.lastIndexOf(','));
        pw.printf("%s,%f%n", l, updatedValues[i]);
    }
    sc.close();
    pw.close();
```

note that updatedValues length should be >= file line count

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.split()` to do this

Here is the Pseduocode:

```
Double[] updatedValues = {33231.23,32344.34}
While (read line from file !=null or empty)
{
String[] tokens= line.split(",");
tokens[2] = "" + updatedValues[i];
//now write the three values in the string array tokens to another file separated by some seperator
}
```